# How to output to terminal but not pipe (or vice versa)

Tags: haskell

I'd like to display some text to the terminal but not send this text to a piped process. The purpose is to format differently the data that is being displayed (for pretty printing) and that which is being sent to subsequent processes.

For example, I would like, once the executable is called like this:

```
$ execname | otherproc
```

to both output something that will be displayed on the terminal and send some string through the pipe to `otherproc`. Is there something, maybe like a `System.IO.Handle` such as `stdout`, that I could use to send data either to be displayed in terminal or to the pipe?

Comment: You want `isatty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to be working: send the data that is meant to be piped to the standard output (with `putStrLn` for example), and the data to be displayed to the file `/dev/tty`. For example, the following send "a" to both:

```
import qualified System.IO as SIO

main = do
    SIO.withFile "/dev/tty" SIO.WriteMode (\h -> SIO.hPutStrLn h "a")
    putStrLn "a"
```

That way, running the shell command

```
$ myProg | sed 's/a/A/'
```

in a terminal displays:

```
a
A
```

Only the second A was replaced, i.e. the one send to sed through the pipe with `putStrLn`, and not the one directly written to `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you make some assumptions. You can check if it is the console by using the [`System.Console.Terminal.Size`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal-size-0.3.2.1/docs/System-Console-Terminal-Size.html#v:size) module:

```
import System.Console.Terminal.Size(size)

isConsole :: IO Bool
isConsole = liftM isJust size
```

basically what happens is it checks if the terminal has defined a size (so it is `Just x`). If so we assume it is a terminal, if not we make the assumption that it is a pipe (which has no size). Of course it is up to a console to specify its size properly.

Comment: I actually need to send different strings to be displayed on the terminal and to the pipe at the same time. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @GuillaumeChérel: in that case they usually send to the stderr, and other outputs...